# Do I need to write a main() function when I've used annotation '@Test' from JUnit while testing Spring Project?

Tags: java, spring, junit

Recently I've been learning Spring framework. And when I tried the code on my book, an error occurred which is

```java
错误: 在类 com.test.app.SpringTest 中找不到 main 方法, 请将 main 方法定义为:
   public static void main(String[] args)
否则 JavaFX 应用程序类必须扩展javafx.application.Application
```

Let me translate this as follows.

```java
Error: cannot find main function in class 'com.test.app.SpringTest', 
please define main function as: ... 
otherwise JavaFX application class must be extended from javafx.application.Application
```

It's also my first time to use JUnit, I've searched for this but cannot find an answer, I will post the structure of my project and also the essential codes below to make it clear.
[Here is the structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLLCR.png)

I'm sure that my maven has downloaded all the jar packages needed.

In applicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

In SprintTest.java

```java
package com.test.app;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
// import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

// @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class SpringTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

and the book tells me to run test(), but when I press the Run button, It just gives me this error. So I wonder if I should add a main function, I know this might be a very simple question and that may be why I cannot find an answer. So please tell me if you know this. Thanks for your help. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've placed your test code under `src/main/java` instead of `src/test/java`, so I doubt the IDE will pick up on it being a test. Move the test code code to `src/test/java` and mark it as a test srouce folder, and you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks really. It seems that it works and the test passed .But I didn't get any outputs in Console which I found when using Eclipse ..